# Equating determinants using properties

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

Prove without expanding
$$ \begin{vmatrix}
a^3 & a^2 & 1 \\ 
b^3 & b^2 & 1 \\
c^3 & c^2 & 1
\end{vmatrix} = (ab + bc + ca)\begin{vmatrix}
a^2 & a & 1 \\
b^2 & b & 1 \\
c^2 & c & 1
\end{vmatrix} $$

Well I tried but can't figure out a way to factor out $ (ab + bc + ca) $ directly without expanding. I can easily show both equal but not directly without expanding.

Comment: Well what i think is to consider if somehow we can convert $ (ab + bc + ca) $ into a determinant

Answer (score 15, accepted):

$$ (ab + bc + ca)\begin{vmatrix}
a^2 & a & 1 \\
b^2 & b & 1 \\
c^2 & c & 1
\end{vmatrix} -\begin{vmatrix}
a^3 & a^2 & 1 \\ 
b^3 & b^2 & 1 \\
c^3 & c^2 & 1
\end{vmatrix}$$
$$=\begin{vmatrix}
a^2 & a(ab+bc+ca)+a^3 & 1 \\ 
b^2 & b(ab+bc+ca)+b^3 & 1 \\
c^2 & c(ab+bc+ca)+c^3 & 1
\end{vmatrix}$$
$$=\begin{vmatrix}
a^2 & a^2(a+b+c)+abc & 1 \\ 
b^2 & b^2(a+b+c)+abc & 1 \\
c^2 & c^2(a+b+c)+abc & 1
\end{vmatrix}=0.$$

Comment: Ah, much neater than mine. +1.

Comment: It's really a beautiful solution 

Answer (score 3):

Let us prove that
$$(Xb+Xc+bc)P(X)+Q(X)=0,$$
where
$$P(X)=\begin{vmatrix}
X^2 &X & 1 \\
b^2 & b & 1 \\
c^2 & c & 1
\end{vmatrix},\quad Q(X)=\begin{vmatrix}
X^2 &X^3& 1 \\
b^2 & b^3& 1 \\
c^2 & c^3& 1
\end{vmatrix}.$$

- The well-known Vandermonde determinant $P(X)$ can be (re-)computed by writing it $P(X)=\lambda(X-b)(X-c)$ where $bc\lambda=P(0)=bc(b-c)$ hence (viewing temporarily $b,c$ also as polynomial indeterminates) $\lambda=b-c$:
  $$P(X)=(b-c)(X-b)(X-c).$$
  Similarly, $Q(X)=(\mu X+bc(c-b))(X-b)(X-c),$ and $\mu=-\begin{vmatrix}
  b^2 & 1 \\
  c^2 &1
  \end{vmatrix}=c^2-b^2,$ i.e.
  $$Q(X)=((c+b)X+bc)(c-b)(X-b)(X-c),$$
  q.e.d.
- Alternatively and more simply (without computing $P(X),Q(X)$ explicitely):
  $P(X),Q(X)$ are polynomials of respective degrees $2,3,$ and $Q$ vanishes at the two (generically distinct) roots $b,c$ of $P$ hence
  $$(\alpha X+\beta)P(X)+Q(X)=0,$$
  where
  $0=\beta P(0)+Q(0)=\beta bc(b-c)+b^2c^2(c-b)$ i.e. (again by genericity) $\beta=bc$ and (identifying the coefficient of $X^3$) $0=\alpha(b-c)+c^2-b^2$ hence (similarly) $\alpha=b+c.$

Comment: Well thanks but can't this question have a more simpler solution 

Answer (score 0):

*This is a solution that involves a single expanding but not of one of the original matrices.*

Observe that the matrix

\begin{vmatrix}
a^2 & a & 1 \\
b^2 & b & 1 \\
c^2 & c & 1
\end{vmatrix}

is a Vandermonde matrix with its first and third row swapped.

the determinant of a Vandermonde matrix
$$\begin{vmatrix}
1 & a & a^2 \\
1 & b & b^2 \\
1 & c & c^2
\end{vmatrix}=(b-a)(c-a)(c-b)$$

but if two rows of a matrix are changed, the sign of its determinant also changes.

Therefore we need to show that

$$\begin{vmatrix}
a^3 & a^2 & 1 \\ 
b^3 & b^2 & 1 \\
c^3 & c^2 & 1
\end{vmatrix}=(a-b)(a-c)(b-c)(ab+bc+ca)$$

but
$$\begin{vmatrix}
a^3 & a^2 & 1 \\ 
b^3 & b^2 & 1 \\
c^3 & c^2 & 1
\end{vmatrix}=$$

$$\begin{vmatrix}
a^3 & a^2 & 1 \\ 
b^3-a^3 & b^2-a^2 & 0 \\
c^3 & c^2 & 1
\end{vmatrix}=$$

$$(b-a)\begin{vmatrix}
a^3 & a^2 & 1 \\ 
b^2+ab+a^2 & b+a & 0 \\
c^3 & c^2 & 1
\end{vmatrix}=$$

$$(b-a)\begin{vmatrix}
a^3 & a^2 & 1 \\ 
b^2+ab+a^2 & b+a & 0 \\
c^3-a^3 & c^2-a^2 & 0
\end{vmatrix}=$$

$$(b-a)(c-a)\begin{vmatrix}
a^3 & a^2 & 1 \\ 
b^2+ab+a^2 & b+a & 0 \\
c^2+ac+a^2 & c+a & 0
\end{vmatrix}=$$

$$(b-a)(c-a)\begin{vmatrix}
a^3 & a^2 & 1 \\ 
b^2+ab+a^2 & b+a & 0 \\
c^2-b^2+a(c-b) & c-b & 0
\end{vmatrix}=$$

$$(b-a)(c-a)\begin{vmatrix}
a^3 & a^2 & 1 \\ 
b^2+ab+a^2 & b+a & 0 \\
(c-b)(c+b)+a(c-b) & c-b & 0
\end{vmatrix}=$$

$$(b-a)(c-a)(c-b)\begin{vmatrix}
a^3 & a^2 & 1 \\ 
b^2+ab+a^2 & b+a & 0 \\
a+b+c & 1 & 0
\end{vmatrix}=$$

By directly (and easily, given the two zeros) computing the determinant $$\begin{vmatrix}
a^3 & a^2 & 1 \\ 
b^2+ab+a^2 & b+a & 0 \\
a+b+c & 1 & 0
\end{vmatrix}=-(ab+bc+ca)$$

we obtain the result.